# Removing contiguous duplicates in ArrayList [Java]

Tags: java, arraylist

I am doing a simple Java program and I need to remove all of the contiguous duplicates in a String ArrayList.

My String ArrayList is something like this:

```
list = [a,b,c,c,d,a,b,c,d]
```

My goal is removing all (and only!) the contiguous duplicates so that the result would be: [a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d]. As you can see, one of the two contiguous "c" has been removed.

I tried something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {

        if (list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i+1))==0) {
            positionToRemove.add(i);
        }

    }
```

Where positionToRemove will at the end contain all the position of the contiguous elements which I will then remove using list.remove() (still not done)

Unfortunately I get

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

I am quite positive there is a very simple way to achieve this but I can't remember it at the moment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last iteration of the `for` loop, `list.get(i+1)` goes beyond the bounds of the list and thus the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. In any array/arraylist, the maximum accessible index is always `size/length - 1`.

To fix that you need to change your logic a bit.

```
for (int i = 1; i<list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i-1).compareTo(list.get(i))==0) {
        positionToRemove.add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have always problem with bounds exceptions, but this proved to be very useful for me in understanding how loops works. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to store the indexes of the elements you need to remove. Just remove it directly by:

```
int size = list.size();
for (int i = size - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    if (list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i - 1)) == 0) {
        list.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you access the `List` using index + 1 or `i+1`, you overstep the bounds of the `List` on the last iteration.  You can fix this by setting the conditional for your `for` loop to `i < list.size() -1`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() -1; i++) {  
        if (list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i+1))==0) {
            positionToRemove.add(i);
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Where positionToRemove will at the end contain all the position of the
>   contiguous elements which I will then remove using list.remove()
>   (still not done)

Instead of storing each position, you could start from the end of the list and directly remove the current element if it's the same as its left neighbour. Using this, you don't need to create another list containing the indexes of the objects you want to remove.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a","b","c","c","d","a","b","c","d"));
for(int i = list.size() - 1; i > 0; i--){
    if(list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i-1)) == 0){
        list.remove(i);
    }
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Which outputs:

```
[a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d]
```

Answer (score 0):

It should not reach the length of your list. You must shutdown the traverses at size -1.

```
for (int i = 0; i<list.size() - 1; i++) {
    if (list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i+1))==0) {
        positionToRemove.add(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Java 7, using iterator.

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = collection.values().iterator();
Integer previousValue = null;

while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Integer currentValue = iterator.next();
    if(currentValue.equals(previousValue)){
        iterator.remove();
    }
    previousValue = currentValue;
}
```